# Can AngularJS inject named instances of factories or services?

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting with Angular with a project that seems really suited to it. In  this project i must make several instances of a form builder so i have decided to make a service out of the form builder code. All is fine and good up until i take in account the other requirement: Form previews.

I was thinking of something along the lines of what [this guy does](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers) but then i realised using his approach implies i cannot store/share more than one form (At least with the default injection approach used by Angular) so i gave it some thought and decided that having one instance of the FormBuilder service for each form would cut it. How can i control *which* instance of my service is injected into my controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Propably you would not inject a specifc FormBuilder instance rather than a InstanceRegistry?

Comment: I kind of understand where your point is going, elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service which returns a function taking the name to resolve and returns the resolved instance. This will be called from your controller.

Optionally, you  could create resolves for the route if you are using  either ngRoute or ui.router and do the resolving in the resolve block.

```
.when("...",{
controller:"...",
templateUrl:"...",
resolve:{
form1:["$formFactory", function($formFactory){
return $formFactory("form1")
})
}
})
```

HTH

Comment: The second approach seems clearer to me, i will use that. Thanks